# Return cities in Wikidata SPARQL Query, similar to a Wikipedia page

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a nice list, but not only are the cities duplicating, but I'm unsure how they're defined as `cities`. I would expect to see `London` in the results and have similar results to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country:_C). These results are quite different to the Wikipedia page.

I want to:

1. Get a list of `cities`, with their `first-level administrative country subdivision` (province/state/region), similar to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country:_C)
2. While avoiding duplicate cities.

```
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel ?country ?population ?countryLabel ?region ?regionLabel ?lat ?long
WHERE 
{
    ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q515 .  # find instances of subclasses of city
    ?city (wdt:P131) ?region.
    ?region wdt:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q10864048 .
    ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
    ?city wdt:P17 ?country .  # Also find the country of the city
    ?city p:P625 ?statement . # coordinate-location statement
    ?statement psv:P625 ?coordinate_node .
    OPTIONAL { ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat. }
    OPTIONAL { ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLongitude ?long.}

    FILTER (?population > 100000) .
    # choose language
    SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
} 
LIMIT 8000
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fpopulation%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fregion%20%3FregionLabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ515%20.%20%20%23%20find%20instances%20of%20subclasses%20of%20city%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%28wdt%3AP131%29%20%3Fregion.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fregion%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ10864048%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%20%20%23%20Also%20find%20the%20country%20of%20the%20city%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP625%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%23%20coordinate-location%20statement%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20psv%3AP625%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong.%7D%0A%0A%20%20%09FILTER%20%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%20100000%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20choose%20language%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0ALIMIT%208000)

**Update:**

Although not an answer to this specific question, anyone trying to get similar data to this should have a look [here](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities).

**Update 2:**

With help in the comments from @UninformedUser, the query is now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?country ?population ?countryLabel ?region ?regionLabel ?lat ?long
WHERE 
{
    ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q515 .  # find instances of subclasses of city
    ?city (wdt:P131) ?region.
    ?region wdt:P31/wdt:P279 wd:Q10864048 .
    ?city p:P1082 ?populationStmt .    
    ?populationStmt ps:P1082 ?population ; pq:P585 ?pop_date .  
    ?city wdt:P17 ?country .  # Also find the country of the city
    ?city p:P625 ?statement . # coordinate-location statement
    ?statement psv:P625 ?coordinate_node .
    OPTIONAL { ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLatitude ?lat. }
    OPTIONAL { ?coordinate_node wikibase:geoLongitude ?long.}
      
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {     
      ?city p:P1082/pq:P585 ?pop_date_ .     
      FILTER (?pop_date_ > ?pop_date)     
    }

    FILTER (?population > 100000) .
    # choose language
    SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    }
} 
LIMIT 8000
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fpopulation%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fregion%20%3FregionLabel%20%3Flat%20%3Flong%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ515%20.%20%20%23%20find%20instances%20of%20subclasses%20of%20city%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20%28wdt%3AP131%29%20%3Fregion.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fregion%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%20wd%3AQ10864048%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%20%3FpopulationStmt%20.%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3FpopulationStmt%20ps%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20%3B%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fpop_date%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%20%20%23%20Also%20find%20the%20country%20of%20the%20city%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP625%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%23%20coordinate-location%20statement%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20psv%3AP625%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLatitude%20%3Flat.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcoordinate_node%20wikibase%3AgeoLongitude%20%3Flong.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20p%3AP1082%2Fpq%3AP585%20%3Fpop_date_%20.%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fpop_date_%20%3E%20%3Fpop_date%29%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%09FILTER%20%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%20100000%29%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20choose%20language%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0ALIMIT%2080)

Comment: regarding duplicates: 1) you have to omit "old countries" that do not exists anymore, as Wikidata also contains historical data, see e.g. http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q188478  2) there can be multiple population values depending on the source, see e.g. phttps://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q423

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that it was happening with regions, but not countries. Do you know how to modify the query to achieve this? This is the first time I've worked with SPARQL.

Comment: something like `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240}` will omit historical countries at least. If that is not sufficient, you can also omit countries with an end date

Comment: you should also do `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: for population, at least taking the latest would be a first step, so instead of `?city wdt:P1082 ?population .` you can do  `?city p:P1082 ?populationStmt .
   ?populationStmt ps:P1082 ?population ;
                   pq:P585 ?pop_date
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?city p:P1082/pq:P585 ?pop_date_ .
    FILTER (?pop_date_ > ?pop_date)
    }`